# Elsevier document class option 5p

Tags: elsarticle

As many of you know, there are different options of Elsevier document which includes:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

\documentclass[final,1p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\documentclass[final,1p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\documentclass[final,3p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\documentclass[final,5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}
```

My question here is, can I have a 5p single-column paper??  What is the difference between (5p) and (5p, twocolumn) ??

When I used `\documentclass[final,5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}`, it gives me a two column layout which I don't need.

Comment: `[5p,onecolumn]` ?

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle but does't help.

Comment: if you don't need two column why are you using a publisher supplied option that is specifically for two column documents?

Comment: Elsevier as a publisher has a 5p journal with single coulmn such as 'Transportation Research Part D' where I am trying to publishmy work

Answer (score 3):

I see nowhere in the documentation that one is supposed to use both `5p` and `twocolumn`.

The option `1p` always uses one column format, while `5p` always uses `twocolumn`:

```
\DeclareOption{5p}{\xdef\jtype{5}\global\preprintfalse
  \ExecuteOptions{twocolumn}}

\DeclareOption{1p}{\xdef\jtype{1}\global\preprintfalse
  \AtBeginDocument{\@twocolumnfalse}}
```

From the code it's clear that passing `twocolumn` together with `5p` is redundant, because the option is executed anyway.

The only option for which a choice between one and two column format is sensible is `3p`.

Passing `5p` and `onecolumn` as options is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> My question here is, can I have a 5p single column paper?

Here's an excerpt from page 2 of the user guide of the `elsarticle` class:

> 5p -- This is always of twocolumn style."

The short, and also the long, answer to your question therefore is: "No".

Comment: Thank you Mico. But if 5p is always for twoclumn, why there are (5p) and (5p, twocolumn) options ???

Comment: @AmeenMohamedBassam - Sorry, I am not the author of this document class. I'm also entirely unfamiliar with the design decisions that had to be made when the document class was created. I thus can't address meaningfully any *why*-type questions related to the `elsarticle` document class. My apologies.

Comment: @AmeenMohamedBassam the 5p option executes twocolum so `5p` is the same as `5p,twocolumn`  `5p,onecolumn` resets one column but as `jype` is 5 many constructs (notably `\maketitle`) are only defined for two column documents.)

Answer (score 0):

*To whom might still be interested in this topic*

I recently encountered the same problem with a paper I am about to submit to *Journal of Computational Physics*. The printed area looks like `5p`, but the page layout is `onecolumn` which is contrary to what is specified in the docs of  `elsarticle.cls`.

The answer is in fact in the [scope of the journal itself](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-computational-physics)

> **Full text articles** have a **recommended length of 35 pages**. In order to estimate the page limit, please use our [template](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/promis_misc/JCOMP-template.zip).

Upon downloading this template, it turns out that, besides the classical `elsarticle.cls` class, J Comp Phys also uses a specific package `jcomp`.